# Unexpected result from Numpy Matrix insert, How does this work?

Tags: python, numpy

My goal was to insert a column to the right on a numpy matrix. However, I found that the code I was using is putting in two columns rather than just one.

```
# This one results in a 4x1 matrix, as expected
np.insert(np.matrix([[0],[0]]), 1, np.matrix([[0],[0]]), 0)
>>>matrix([[0],
           [0],
           [0],
           [0]])
# I would expect this line to return a 2x2 matrix, but it returns a 2x3 matrix instead.
np.insert(np.matrix([[0],[0]]), 1, np.matrix([[0],[0]]), 1)
>>>matrix([[0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0]]
```

Why do I get the above, in the second example, instead of `[[0,0], [0,0]]`?

Comment: are you sure you want to use a matrix?

Comment: @PaulH Not entirely sure. It was my go-to since the matrix I'll eventually be working with will be a large 2-dimensional grid of numbers. But I don't know how it would compare to other numpy structures.

Comment: 98% sure you just want a `np.array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While new use of `np.matrix` is discouraged, we get the same result with `np.array`:

```
In [41]: np.insert(np.array([[1],[2]]),1, np.array([[10],[20]]), 0)                                          
Out[41]: 
array([[ 1],
       [10],
       [20],
       [ 2]])
In [42]: np.insert(np.array([[1],[2]]),1, np.array([[10],[20]]), 1)                                          
Out[42]: 
array([[ 1, 10, 20],
       [ 2, 10, 20]])

In [44]: np.insert(np.array([[1],[2]]),1, np.array([10,20]), 1)                                              
Out[44]: 
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20]])
```

Insert as [1]:

```
In [46]: np.insert(np.array([[1],[2]]),[1], np.array([[10],[20]]), 1)                                        
Out[46]: 
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20]])
In [47]: np.insert(np.array([[1],[2]]),[1], np.array([10,20]), 1)                                            
Out[47]: 
array([[ 1, 10, 20],
       [ 2, 10, 20]])
```

`np.insert` is a complex function written in Python.  So we need to look at that code, and see how `values` are being mapped on the target space.

The docs elaborate on the difference between insert at `1` and `[1]`.  But off hand I don't see an explanation of how the shape of `values` matters.

```
Difference between sequence and scalars:

>>> np.insert(a, [1], [[1],[2],[3]], axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
>>> np.array_equal(np.insert(a, 1, [1, 2, 3], axis=1),
...                np.insert(a, [1], [[1],[2],[3]], axis=1))
True
```

When adding an array at the end of another, I'd use `concatenate` (or one of its `stack` variants) rather than `insert`.  None of these operate in-place.

```
In [48]: np.concatenate([np.array([[1],[2]]), np.array([[10],[20]])], axis=1)                                
Out[48]: 
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20]])
```