# NumPy Insert Function: what are the effects of using a single integer index vs a list of indices? How is shape affected?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have been studying NumPy for a while and a strange behavior stopped me.

I hope the following code snippets could help:

This is the array that I will be working with :
`e = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3,3))`.

1- Insert values to a rank 1 array:
`np.insert(e, 0, [1,2,3])` and `np.insert(e, [0], [1,2,3])` are equivalent.
**output:**  `array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`.

2- Insert values to a rank 2 array (rows):
`np.insert(e, 0, [10,11,12], axis=0)` and `np.insert(e, [0], [10,11,12], axis=0)` are equivalent.
Notice that I didn't use the shape of a row -`[[10,11,12]]`- and it works just fine.

Even though, I tried `np.insert(e, 0, [[10,11,12]], axis=0)` and `np.insert(e, [0], [[10,11,12]], axis=0)` and obtained the same results.

```
output:
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
```

And as expected using either `np.insert(e, [0,2], [10,11,12], axis=0)` or `np.insert(e, [0,2], [[10,11,12]], axis=0)` will insert the row into two different places in the array.

```
output:
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
```

**Now to the strange behaviors.**

3- Insert values to a rank 2 array (columns):
a. (1)`np.insert(e, 0, [10,11,12], axis=1)` VS (2)`np.insert(e, [0], [10,11,12], axis=1)`.
b. (3)`np.insert(e, 0, [[10],[11],[12]], axis=1)` Vs (4)`np.insert(e, [0], [[10],[11],[12]], axis=1)`.

```
a. outputs from (1) and (4):
array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [11,  4,  5,  6],
       [12,  7,  8,  9]])
```

```
b. outputs from (2) and (3):
array([[10, 11, 12,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12,  4,  5,  6],
       [10, 11, 12,  7,  8,  9]])
```

c. (5)`np.insert(e, [0,2], [[10],[11],[12]], axis=1)` VS (6)`np.insert(e, [0,2], [10,11,12], axis=1)`.

```
output from (5):
array([[10,  1,  2, 10,  3],
       [11,  4,  5, 11,  6],
       [12,  7,  8, 12,  9]])
```

```
The output from (6):
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,3)
```

1- If the shape is optional as in the row example, why this is not the case for columns in codes (1) and (4)?

2- If the shape is important, why did it work for (4) but not (3)?

3- If the shape is mandatory then, what is the difference between (5) and (6)? Why would NumPy broadcast this list of elements in (6)?

Comment: `np.insert` is a complex python function, taking different approaches depending on  the inputs.  Sooner later ut concatenates some arrays, or creates a recipient array and copies arrays to it.  You could do the same and probably faster.

Comment: I vaguely recall answering a similar question (with in the last year or 2).  The interplay between `object` (esp. whether scalar or list) and the `values` shape is hard to sort out.  The docs attempts to explain this.  I'm not sure I want to take the time to revisit it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57365728/unexpected-result-from-numpy-matrix-insert-how-does-this-work/57365808#57365808

Comment: I think in all these cases `insert` calculates the return result from the size (and type) of the `object` and `values`.  It copies the original to appropriate spaces, and then copies values.  With 2 insert 'columns' and 3 (or (3,1)) values, it could expand the output shape by 2, or 6 (2 x 3).

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that:

```
`values` should be shaped so that ``arr[...,obj,...] = values``
is legal.
```

Here's an example:

inserting 2 rows into a (3,3) array:

```
In [19]: e=np.zeros((3,3),int)
In [32]: res=np.insert(e,[0,2],[1,2,3],axis=0)
In [33]: res
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

The result is a (5,3) array.  The inserted values can be accessed with:

```
In [34]: res[[0,3],:]
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

That's a (2,3) array.

(I had to change the (0,2) to (0,3) to take into account the inserted row.  `insert` makes that kind of adjustment.

I can assign a (3,) to a (2,3) slot.  By broadcasting that's expanded to (1,3) and on to (2,3):

```
In [35]: res[[0,3],:] = [1,2,3]
```

But a (3,1) cannot be broadcasted:

```
In [36]: res[[0,3],:] = [[1],[2],[3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-36-de940597bcbf>", line 1, in <module>
    res[[0,3],:] = [[1],[2],[3]]
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,1)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,3)
```

Your (6) has the same problem, but with columns:

```
In [38]: res=np.insert(e,[0,2],3,axis=1)
In [39]: res
Out[39]: 
array([[3, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 3, 0]])
In [40]: res[:,[0,3]]            # a (3,2) insert
Out[40]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 3]])
In [41]: res[:,[0,3]] = np.ones((3,2))
In [42]: res[:,[0,3]] = np.ones((3,1))  # broadcasts fine
```

But (3,) and (1,3) can't be put in a (3,2) space:

```
In [43]: res[:,[0,3]] = np.ones((3,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-43-3a546b2939fc>", line 1, in <module>
    res[:,[0,3]] = np.ones((3,))
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,3)

In [44]: res[:,[0,3]] = np.ones((1,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-44-6858764218b0>", line 1, in <module>
    res[:,[0,3]] = np.ones((1,3))
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (1,3)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,3)
```

I'm puzzled as to why the error message says `to indexing result of shape (2,3)`.  I'd expect to to read (3,2).

For reference, here's the full traceback with the `insert` error:

```
In [45]: np.insert(e, [0,2], [10,11,12], axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-45-a7ae562f20c6>", line 1, in <module>
    np.insert(e, [0,2], [10,11,12], axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in insert
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4678, in insert
    new[tuple(slobj)] = values
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,3)
```

`new` must be an array with shape (3,5), `tuple(slobj)` something like `(slice(None), np.array([0,3]))` (comprable to my `[:,[0,3]]`), and `values` is the `np.array([10,11,12])` array.